# Sqlite double left outer join with count

Tags: sqlite, count, left-join

I have the following DB structure:

- tbl_record(_id,_id_user,...)
- tbl_photo(_id,_id_record,...)
- tbl_note(_id,_id_record,...)

When listing the records of a specific user while counting the number of photos a record has, I use the following query, which works fine:

```
SELECT tbl_record._id, COUNT(tbl_photo._id_record) AS photo_count FROM tbl_record
   LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_photo ON tbl_record._id=tbl_photo._id_record
WHERE tbl_record._id_user=? GROUP BY tbl_record._id;
```

Now, I'd like to do the same as above, but also count the number of notes a record has:

```
SELECT tbl_record._id, COUNT(tbl_photo._id_record) AS photo_count, COUNT(tbl_note._id_record) AS note_count FROM tbl_record
   LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_photo ON tbl_record._id=tbl_photo._id_record
   LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_note ON tbl_record._id=tbl_note._id_record
WHERE tbl_record._id_user=? GROUP BY tbl_record._id;
```

The count of the 2nd query does not work properly when a record has >0 photos & >0 notes,  e.g. 3 photos & 5 photos which results in a count of 15 (3*5) for each.

Any idea how to make the 2nd query return the proper counts?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to filter out duplicates by using `COUNT(DISTINCT some_id)`, but this would be inefficient.
Better use correlated subqueries:

```
SELECT _id,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM tbl_photo
        WHERE _id_record = tbl_record._id
       ) AS photo_count,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM tbl_note
        WHERE _id_record = tbl_record._id
       ) AS note_count
FROM tbl_record
WHERE _id_user = ?
```

Comment: Hey CL,
thanks for your fast response! The solution with the correlated subqueries, was exactly what I was looking for.
The DISTINCT solution does also work, got it working this way before I saw your answer (...COUNT(DISTINCT tbl_photo._id) AS photo_count, COUNT(DISTINCT tbl_note._id) AS note_count...), but the correlated subquery performance is much better, especially for the query with the two correlated subqueries compared to two outer joins...
Thx!